# angularjs databinding for uploadcare.com doesnt work

Tags: angularjs, data-binding, 2-way-object-databinding

I'm trying to integrate an upload script into my page. Im using uploadcare.com. They provided a simple directive but I just can't get it to work:

```
https://github.com/uploadcare/angular-uploadcare/blob/master/angular-uploadcare.js
```

I'm setting ng-model="test" and in my controller I have the following:

```
angular.module('testApp')
  .controller('MyCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.test = "test";
  });
```

The html code looks like that:

```
<uploadcare-widget ng-model="test" data-public-key="xyz" />
```

When I check Firebug I can see that the widget works:

```
<input type="hidden" role="uploadcare-uploader" ng-model="test" data-public-key="6e0958899488d61fd5d0" data-crop="1200:630" value="http://www.ucarecdn.com/ca5513da-90f1-40d1-89e7-648237xxxxxx/-/crop/2560x1344/0,128/-/preview/" class="ng-isolate-scope ng-valid">
```

But this input value is never populated back to my "$scope.test". Why is that?
When I output $scope.test it still says "test" instead of my image path value.

Comment: @yretuta Are you using the newest version of this directive? The v0.1.0 doesn't seem like it handled data-binding correctly. See this commit here: https://github.com/uploadcare/angular-uploadcare/commit/c048f4651723366e7b163c8335567feedc2362a9

Answer (score 2):

You can use $watch in angular

```
$scope.$watch('test', function(newValue, oldValue) {
    console.log($scope.test);
});
```

Or the function provided by uploadcare

```
$scope.onUCUploadComplete = function(info){
  console.log(info);
};
```

Which is a callback function after image is uploaded

Answer (score 1):

Please check the scope of test model.
You can also update scope variable inside directive like

```
scope.test = $element.value()
```